# python: Поиск в txt максимально близкого значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка

```py
gur = (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6)
```

Есть файл txt примерно такого вида:

```
(7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6)
(5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6)
(3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4)
(5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8)
(5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8)
(6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7)
(7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 5, 7, 7)
(5, 12, 11, 8, 6, 11, 8, 6)
(4, 13, 9, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5)
(13, 7, 6, 14, 10, 4, 5, 14)
(8, 6, 7, 8, 12, 4, 3, 7)
(8, 3, 9, 10, 3, 1, 6, 10)
(4, 11, 7, 8, 6, 8, 3, 5)
```

Как найти в этом файле наиболее близкое значение переменной `gur` - близкое именно по числам?

Comment: сумма модулей отклонений?

Comment: Надо чтоб каждое число учитывалось в переменной gur!

Comment: То есть если в файле есть значение (6, 12, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6) - отклонение только по одной цифре то выбиралось именно это значение! Но отклонение необязательно по одной цифре!

Comment: вы решите про критерий близости - количество или качество отклонений. например 1,2,3,4  -что "ближе" 10,2, 3,4 или 2,1, 4, 3 ?

Comment: Именно 2,1, 4, 3 будет ближе - то есть надо минимальное отклонение от каждой цифры!

Comment: ну и считайте сумму модулей отклонений для каждой строки

Comment: Сумма не подойдёт - важно отклонение именно каждой цифры и место цифры тоже важно! Сумма точно не подойдёт! Думал перебором изменять значение цифры вычитая и плюсуя - не вариант - код будет длинною с Эверест!

Comment: Что ближе - три отклонения по 1, или два по 1 и одно 2? Три по 2 или 1, 2, 3 по одному?

Comment: @rugami55 вы понимаете, что такое "сумма модулей отклонений"?

Comment: gur = (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6) Я понимаю это так - если я буду искать по сумме модулей отклонений то программа мне выдаст строки например (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5) и (5, 10, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6) - как идентичные! Кстати  (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5) предпочтительнее чем (5, 10, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6)

Comment: Объясните чётко, чем (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5) предпочтительнее (5, 10, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6). Вы же понимаете, что если критерий близости только у вас в голове, то мы вам ничем помочь не сможем? Как вы хотите, чтобы мы решили задачу, для которой вы не сообщили нам важнейшую часть условия?

Comment: Xander - да согласен с вами! Первый ряд цифр имеет главное значение (6, 11, 2, 6,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот вам заготовка с сортировкой от самых ближних по метрике значений, до самых дальних. Обычно в качестве метрики используется сумма квадратов разностей, но можно и сумму абсолютных разностей использовать и другие метрики:

```
gur = (6, 11, 2, 6, 6, 7, 10, 6)
data = (
(7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6),
(5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6),
(3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4),
(5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8),
(5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8),
(6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7),
(7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 5, 7, 7),
(5, 12, 11, 8, 6, 11, 8, 6),
(4, 13, 9, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5),
(13, 7, 6, 14, 10, 4, 5, 14),
(8, 6, 7, 8, 12, 4, 3, 7),
(8, 3, 9, 10, 3, 1, 6, 10),
(4, 11, 7, 8, 6, 8, 3, 5),
)

print(*sorted(data, key=lambda x: sum((a-b)**2 for a, b in zip(gur, x))), sep='\n')
```

Вывод (от самых ближних по метрике, до самых дальних):

```
(5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8)
(7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 5, 7, 7)
(4, 11, 7, 8, 6, 8, 3, 5)
(4, 13, 9, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5)
(5, 12, 11, 8, 6, 11, 8, 6)
(6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7)
(5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8)
(5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6)
(3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4)
(8, 6, 7, 8, 12, 4, 3, 7)
(7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6)
(8, 3, 9, 10, 3, 1, 6, 10)
(13, 7, 6, 14, 10, 4, 5, 14)
```

С метрикой `abs(a-b)` вывод будет уже немного другой:

```
(4, 11, 7, 8, 6, 8, 3, 5)
(5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8)
(5, 12, 11, 8, 6, 11, 8, 6)
(5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6)
(7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 5, 7, 7)
(5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8)
(6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7)
(4, 13, 9, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5)
(3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4)
(7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6)
(8, 6, 7, 8, 12, 4, 3, 7)
(8, 3, 9, 10, 3, 1, 6, 10)
(13, 7, 6, 14, 10, 4, 5, 14)
```

Одно значение можно получить, если использовать `min` вместо `sorted`:

```
print(min(data, key=lambda x: sum((a-b)**2 for a, b in zip(gur, x))))
```

Вывод:

```
(5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: Нужно одно значение самое близкое!

Comment: Ну просто берёте первое значение и всё. Щас код допишу, ладно. Просто списком нагляднее видно, какие значения ближе, а какие дальше получились.